# how to compile a windows 7 compatible binary on visusal studio 2015

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015 on windows 10. I want to compile a windows 7 compatible binary file. But there is no windows 7 option in the project properties. When I put the binary on windows 7, it told me "The procedure entry point CreateEventExA could not located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll"

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 on the target machine. Here is the link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer addressed the `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable` (v140 of mscvrt) but this isn't enough to get your binary working on Windows that hasn't been updated to the Universal CRT (Windows 8.1 SP1 and up).

For more information:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx

In a nutshell, copy all the DLLs from
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt` to the target machine.

-OR-

You can install Visual Studio 2012 and use its toolset which will enable your program to link against msvcrt110.dll and run out of the box on Windows 7.

Set The toolset by `right clicking your project -> properties -> General -> Platfrom Toolset -> Visual Studio 2012 (v110)`

Comment: From the blog post you linked to - *The Visual Studio 2015 VCRedist package includes the above mentioned Windows Update packages, so simply installing the VCRedist will install both the Visual C++ libraries and the Universal CRT*. So why is the other answer to install the redistributable incomplete?

Comment: I don't know and also don't understand why my answer was down voted.

Comment: This answer take UCRT into consideration therefore relevant to the topic