# Can one compile Windows code on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, compilation

I have an Ubuntu server (with a VPN and a samba share), where I store all my project files and so on.

I would like not to have to back up the files I have on my computer to the server, but instead, directly use the files that are on the server.

But, when I want to build a project on Windows, it gets really slow, since I basically have to be transferring that whole bunch of files visual studio creates through the internet, so I can build the project.

The core concept is:

- Open files that are on the server and use them (ie. saving one file at a time is fast enough not to make a difference).
- Compile the code on Linux (Maybe code a VS extension with sockets that will tell the server to build, and that server-side, when done building, will send a message back, for VS to run and debug the program). Which would be much better since my laptop is nothing compared to the server performance-wise.
- Run and debug the program with VS on windows.

I've so far only been able to find [this](http://www.blogcompiler.com/2010/07/11/compile-for-windows-on-linux/)(which is not what I want because it uses g++, and I'd like VC++) and [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/)(which is not what I want because it's compiling for linux and executing it remotely). What I'm looking for is a mixture of both.

Remote compiling, local programming and executing.

Would also be great because supposedly, I could build with whatever VC++ version I wanted with whatever SDK I wanted. So I could basically easily switch between compiling for Windows 7 and 10.

I'd just like to know: Is it possible to achieve that? And if so how?

Comment: *"easily switch between compiling for windows 7 and 10"* - Huh? That's **one** preprocessor define you have to change. There isn't any more to it.

Comment: @IInspectable I've [read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792402/how-to-compile-a-windows-7-compatible-binary-on-visusal-studio-2015) otherwise.

Comment: All that link says is that you have to install the runtime libraries on the Windows 7 machine.  But you have to do that for a Windows 7 target no matter what version of Visual Studio you use.  (Well, unless you go back to Visual Studio 6, but I wouldn't recommend it.)  You won't gain anything by using, say, Visual Studio 2010 for Windows 7 rather than Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2):

Using VC++ directly on Linux is not possible.
To let the Linux server do the compiling with VC++ anyway you could either use wine which apparently works with older Versions (see https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5766
) but propably is not easy to set up in a CLI envrioment and might cause License Issues with Microsoft, or use Windows Virtual Machines, which tend to have some Performance drawback.

The best Solution would be to use GCC (g++), which works on a wide range of architectures and operating systems and supports cross compiling.

Comment: I don't remember exactly which, but I remember running into bugs with g++ when starting out, which made me move away from it. I guess that at this point I should have a fair amount of ease dealing with those.  Thank you, I'll look into it.

Comment: @TrisT: Code written for Visual Studio often fails to compile or run as expected when compiled with a different compiler. Visual Studio is very lenient when it comes to enforcing language rules. Many constructs that are undefined according to the language specification will reliably work with Visual Studio (e.g. type punning in C++). If you want to grow as a developer and produce better code, compiling with different compilers is almost guaranteed to bring up questions that you haven't previously thought about asking.